# Azure deployment to web role stuck in transitioning state

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We been using Azure Cloud services for nearly a year now so our periodic deployment process has been pretty stable.

Today we built deployment packages through VS2013 (which we have been doing) 
I went to update the web role roll.
Package was uploaded
Package was uploaded to the production environment
However the role has been stuck in a transitioning state for around 2 hours now?

Normally this deployment to a 2 instance web role takes about 20 minutes.

Other than being in a state of transitioning there is little other feedback for me to know if something was wrong with our package or if the Azure deployment will eventually fail.

Fortunately our apps have remained up although it doesn't appear our updated code has been deployed yet.

Has anyone had issues with a deployment getting stuck in transitioning state and know if the process will eventually finish or die on it's own??

Thanks,
James Whittington

Comment: A quick update to my issue. After 2 hours I noticed my chrome browser did not show things transitioning anymore. I closed my IE browser and reopened and the transition state was gone. It appears our updated code made it to the role. However Azure operation logs show that the UpgradeDeploymentBySlot process Started 2 hours ago and there is no coresponding Succeeded Status like we would see on a successful deployment. I think the Azure Management portal just lost track of the deployment